# Cfloop inside cfloop?

Tags: coldfusion, cfloop

I have a question about my cfloop inside of another cfloop. Here is my code:

```
<cfloop from="1" to="5" index="k">
    <cfloop from="#qry.S#" to="#qry.E#" index="i" step="#CreateTimeSpan(0,0,qry.Leng,0)#">
        <cfset TimeEnd = dateAdd("n", Leng, i)>
            <tr>
                <td>(#k#) #timeFormat(TimeStart, "hh:mm tt")# - #timeFormat(TimeEnd, "hh:mm tt")#</td>
            </tr>
        <cfset TimeStart = dateAdd("n", qry.Leng, i)>           
    </cfloop>   
</cfloop>
```

This code above gives me output like this:

```
    09:00 AM - 09:15 AM
    09:15 AM - 09:30 AM
    09:30 AM - 09:45 AM
    09:45 AM - 10:00 AM
   *10:00 AM - 09:15 AM
    09:15 AM - 09:30 AM
    09:30 AM - 09:45 AM
    09:45 AM - 10:00 AM
   *10:00 AM - 09:15 AM
    09:15 AM - 09:30 AM
    09:30 AM - 09:45 AM
    09:45 AM - 10:00 AM
   *10:00 AM - 09:15 AM
    09:15 AM - 09:30 AM
    09:30 AM - 09:45 AM
    09:45 AM - 10:00 AM
   *10:00 AM - 09:15 AM
    09:15 AM - 09:30 AM
    09:30 AM - 09:45 AM
    09:45 AM - 10:00 AM
```

As you can see I put the star next to the line where my code gives me wrong values. For some reason my start time after first loop is done once, starts from the end time. Can anyone tell me how this can be fixed?

Comment: What troubleshooting of your own have you done? There's no evidence here of what you've done to try to sort this out yourself? Can I recommend you at least desk-check the first iteration of the outer loop and verify your expectations. Also provide us with an SSCCE (sscce.org), not simply an extract of the code. We should be able to *run* the example you are troubleshooting (and that should be the same code *you* are troubleshooting).

Comment: I done a lot troubleshooting(different for loop ex: cfloop condition=""), output values on the screen, used different time slots, etc. Problem was that I haven't reset the times outside of my cfloop that creates time slots. Once I fixed that my first problem was solved. Now I have a problem if I have only one time slot my code makes duplicate.

Comment: Why did you waste people's time asking the same question twice?

Comment: Question is not the same, you can take a look and find the difference. Thank you.

Comment: It amounts to the same question: not not having a handle on loop nesting.

Answer (score 3):

You can't use "i" as the index for both the outer and inner loop. Use something else for the inner loop (x). For example:

```
<cfloop from="1" to="5" index="i">
    <cfloop from="#qry.S#" to="#qry.E#" index="x" step="#CreateTimeSpan(0,0,qry.Leng,0)#">
        <cfset TimeEnd = dateAdd("n", Leng, i)>
            <tr>
                <td> #timeFormat(TimeStart, "hh:mm tt")# - #timeFormat(TimeEnd, "hh:mm tt")#</td>
            </tr>
        <cfset TimeStart = dateAdd("n", qry.Leng, i)>           
    </cfloop>   
</cfloop>
```

I'm not sure of the intention here so you may need to swap some of you i's for x's in the inner loop depending on what you are after (start-end for example).

*************************** edits ****************

Maybe I see your issue (not sure) but based on your comment your issue is going to be that you have reset the timestart var. You need to do that after your first loop begins.

```
<cfloop> outer loop
    <Cfset timestart = *starting value*>
      <cfloop> inner looop
```

Other wise your timestart is going to be whatever your last cfset for it was - in the inner loop.

Comment: I already changed my index values to be different. Still that will not give me the output that I want. My start time always should start same as first time in this case 9:00am.

Comment: I added an additional edit to my answer. Let me know if it helps.

Comment: You were right that helped me to fix Start time issue but there is one more. If I have multiple time slots like I showed in my question above my code works fine now, but if I have just start time 8:00am and ent time 9:00am that should give me 5 time slots in this case, but my code gives me 10, makes duplicate for each k. Do you know maybe why thats happening?

Comment: Very hard to answer - perhaps post your revised code. It's going to loop 5 times no matter what based on the code above. in your inner loop your creating a float as your var (that's what comes back from `createtimespan()` ) so it's hard to tell exactly what is happening. Try `<cfdump var="#createtimespan(0,0,qry.leng,0)#">` and see what sort of value is being produced by your step.

Comment: To be clear that var is a number... maybe a float, probably calculated from specific time - julian maybe. You can look up how it's generated.

Comment: This is the value that I got for interval of 5min = 0.00347222222222. Is there an other way how I can do this? I need two loops because I'm inserting ID from query with the first loop, here for example I just set from 1 to 5.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/97434/discussion-between-user3023588-and-mark-a-kruger).

Comment: If you are only using Minutes, then you can use integers here instead, but you will have more math to do :)